# What is the meaning of return only in JAVA?

Tags: java, constructor, return

I don't know what is the usage `return;`. What does it mean ? Does it return something ? I think `return` keyword use to put back some value but I am not sure because if constructors return only instance of class below code should be invalid.

```
public class Test {
 public Test() {
    return;
 }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Constructors don't return anything. At the byte code level, they are the same as a method which returns `void`

Comment: would you like to point out of my thinking *...I am not sure because if constructors return only instance of class* ?

Comment: You can be sure that a Constructor never returns anything, the instance or anything else.  When you create an object, it is passed to the constructor as an argument for initialisation. It is not returned.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If so my assumption may be concern with `new` keword. Am I right ?

Comment: The `new` is the one which creates the object.  The constructor is called to initialise this object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not returns anything.

It means the end of any method which returns void, so in this case, it means the end of the constructor. See the example below:

```
class Test {

    private int sum;

     public Test(Object otherObj) {
        if (otherObj != null){
           sum = 42;
           return;
        }
        sum = 0;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test testZero = new Test(null);
        Test testNonZero = new Test(testZero);

        System.out.println(testZero.sum);       // 0
        System.out.println(testNonZero.sum);    // 42
    }
}
```

if the `otherObj` is not null, the `sum`'ll be 42, and the constructor will stop running.

You can use the same strategy, if you have a `public void someFunction()` method, to exit at some point.

Comment: Not only for constructors. In this case, yes, but I think that saying "It means the end of the constructor" is misleading. It also means the end of any method which returns void.